# Publish using MSBuild outputs to unexpected path

Tags: .net, msbuild, visual-studio-2015

I am using the following command to publish my application for ClickOnce:

```
D:\Builds\Client.App>"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MsBuild.exe" /m "Client\Client.csproj" /target:publish /property:VisualStudioVersion=14.0;ApplicationVersion=%version%;OutputPath="Client\bin\Release"
```

This ends up creating the expected files, but in this path:

```
D:\Builds\Client.App\Client\bin\Releaseapp.publish
```

Notice the lack of path separator before the "app.publish"?

I've tried specifying the "PublishUrl" on the command line also, to no avail:

```
D:\Builds\Client.App>"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MsBuild.exe" /m "Client\Client.csproj" /target:publish /property:Configuration=Release;Platform="Any CPU";VisualStudioVersion=14.0;ApplicationVersion=%version%;OutputPath="%cd%\Client\bin\Release";PublishUrl="%cd%\Client\bin\Release\app.publish"
```

I have used the %cd% in order to ensure that relative paths aren't being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another slash after \Release

```
D:\Builds\Client.App>"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MsBuild.exe" /m "Client\Client.csproj" /target:publish /property:VisualStudioVersion=14.0;ApplicationVersion=%version%;OutputPath="Client\bin\Release\"
```

If that doesn't work then you can use PublishDir property to explicitly specify the final clickonce output folder (msbuild would only append the default 'app.publish' folder to OutputRoot if PublishDir is not set).

Comment: Doing that (adding a trailing slash) results in an "invalid char in path" error.

Comment: Weird; that's how all my msbuild builds are set up and it never complained. What you can do then is use PublishDir property to specify the final folder. MSBuild will only append the default 'app.publish' folder to OutputPath if the PublishDir property is not set